# python introspection - get name of variable passed to function

Tags: python, introspection

I'd like to be able to access the name of a variable that is passed to a function as e.g.

```
def f(x):
    '''Returns name of list/dict variable passed to f'''
    return magic(x)

>>a = [1,2,3]
>>print( f(a) )
'a'
>>print( f(2) )
None
```

I suspect this is possible using Python introspection but I don't know enough to understand the inspect module. (NB I know that the need for a function like magic() is questionable, but it *is* what I want.)

Comment: *"but it is what I want"* - why? What are you actually trying to **achieve** with this? And why did I have to Google that for you?

Comment: Now that I see that this is a duplicate question, I'm reversing my upvote of the question to a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is not possible. In Python names and values are quite separate. Inside `f`, you have access to the *value* of `x`, but it **is not possible** to find out what other *names* other functions might have given to that value.

Think of names as being somewhat like pointers in C. If you have a pointer, you can find out what object it points to. But if you have the object, you cannot find out what pointers are pointing to it.

Comment: You probably *shouldn't*, but it is possible.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - How? Even with stack shenanigans... oh, wait. Maybe it is possible, if you then compared each of the calling stack's names to `x` via reference equality. Ugh, what an ugly hack that would be.

Comment: Yeah, it's... not pretty.

Comment: @jonsharpe +1 for providing the right answer. -1 for not being patient or polite.